# What is causing the Elasticsearch bulk load to fail?

Tags: bash, elasticsearch, curl, search, bulk-load

I can't figure out why I can't bulk load Elasticsearch with JSON. I've done this before but this time I am totally stumped.

I have processed a set of JSON documents into [Elastic Bulk Load Format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) and am trying to bulk load the index I just created (verified created, can be queried, and is empty).

```json
{"create": {"_id": "ef68e997-c616-4b0b-b08e-dfc09f8cb08f"}}
{"id": "ef68e997-c616-4b0b-b08e-dfc09f8cb08f", "title": "My document"}

... repeats for all records
```

The command I run uses a list of paths to the JSON bulk files and a loop to curl/POST them to Elastic using credentials:

```sh
while IFS= read -r "path" < "${DOC_LIST_PATH}"
do
    echo "Submitting Elastic formatted docs at ${path} to Elastic index 'docs' ..."
    
    curl \
    -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" \
    "https://${ES_USER}:${ES_PASSWD}@${ES_HOSTNAME}:${ES_PORT}/docs/_bulk" \
    --data-binary "@${path}" 
done
```

I've done all this before and it should work but... it doesn't. I get this error instead:

```sh
Submitting Elastic formatted docs at data/docs.json/part-00000.json to Elastic index 'docs' ...
Warning: Couldn't read data from file
Warning: "data/docs.json/part-00000.json",
Warning: this makes an empty POST.
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"request body is required"}],"type":"parse_exception","reason":"request body is required"},"status":400}

... repeats for all files
```

I have found that the problem is with this bash code, not the data or the bulk load request:

```sh
--data-binary "@${path}"
```

If I replace that with this, it works:

```sh
--data-binary "@data/docs.json/part-00000.json"
```

Making the full working command for a single file:

```sh
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" "https://${ES_USER}:${ES_PASSWD}@${ES_HOSTNAME}:${ES_PORT}/docs/_bulk" --data-binary "@data/docs.json/part-00000.json"
```

But I need to script this, so this is still maddening. Please help!

This example is also in a [gist here](https://gist.github.com/rjurney/7aa024b66f7391403747cd84a8bec071)

Comment: The error message shows `data_elastic.json`, but it's `data.json` in the working command. Is that a typo? And have you made sure whatever file `DOC_LIST_PATH` points to doesn't contain any invisible characters?

Comment: @oguz_ismail it is a mistake in editing things for posting not in the actual command

Comment: Okay. You checked the file in DOC_LIST_PATH for invisible characters right?